# Django updating values to OneToOneField field

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hi I have User object imported from auth and different model named UserProfile which has bio of user

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    bio=models.TextField(null=True,blank=True, max_length=128)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user
```

as the user is **OneToOneField** Im having inserting data into it

```
q=User.objects.get(id=1)
>>> <User: test>

q.userprofile_set.create(bio='check')
```

Im getting error **'User' object has no attribute 'userprofile_set'**. Im new to django..How should I insert data which has a OneToOneField

Any help is much appreciated...Thnaks in advance

Comment: The _set is added for one to many relations

Answer (score 2):

ManyToManyFields and Foreignkey fields create a object.relation_set property on the object you can follow, but OneToOneFields do not. Instead you use object.relation directly (since we know there's only one).

So try `q.userprofile.create(bio="check")` instead!

(Bonus tip: Whenever you want to see the properties of a python object, use the dir() method, it will show you the full list of properties available!)

Comment: @Emil..Im getting "RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no userprofile." error

Comment: That makes sense. Now you're making the correct query, but your user has no profile, you need to create one first.

Comment: Hey could you please help me writing query for this one......Im just trying to add data into bio for particular user...Thanks mate for spending your time

Comment: Try this:

userprofile = Userprofile()
userprofile.user = q
userprofile.bio = "YOUR TEXT"
userprofile.save()